# Behaviour of activity on minimising Android program

Tags: android

How do I fire an event when my Android program is closed or minimised? Is it also possible to fire an event when a minimised program is killed?

Comment: **Override** `onDestroy` and `onPause` method.

Answer (score 1):

See the Activity life cycle [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) and you will get to know everything you want.